# How to get all attributes value in a specific node

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Here is simple HTML Code

```
<div>
    <img src="http://myImg.com/img/dog_0" orginal="http://myImg.com/dog_a0" alternate="http://myImg.com/img/dog_" />
<div>
```

How to select all attributes (including values) in a specific tag (img) by xpath query?

I have tried

```
$attr = $xpath->query('//div/img/@value');
print_r ($attr);  // DOMNodeList Object ( )
```

I would like have a return as `src="http://myImg.com/img/dog_0" orginal="http://myImg.com/dog_a0" alternate="http://myImg.com/img/dog_"`

Comment: Please stop putting all your text in blockquotes (ie, prefixing with `>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming you want to get all the attributes for all the `<img>` elements that are children of `<div>` elements...

```
$images = $xpath->query('//div/img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    foreach ($image->attributes as $attr) {
        echo $attr->name, ' = ', $attr->value, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Demo - http://ideone.com/gf6sud

Comment: I'm trying and thank you, and also I'm so sorry for my POST I'm new here so I can make my question in proper rule